# Can low battery percentage (like 10%) affect phone heating when charging?

Tags: overheating

I have LG V20 and I like to play Cyber Hunter Lite on low graphics, high resolution and high fps but I don't understand why it sometimes heat so much when playing, sometimes absolutely not, even when charging with 2A, usually no heat. I use KillApps app to kill all processes and leave only Messenger, Facebook...  only about four, reboot phone and use "Boosting" app (called Dr. Booster) to launch the game. But now it heat a lot, and can't touch the screen how it gets after 10 mins of gameplay. But my situation is exceptional. My battery percentage is only 10% now. Usually I charge and play the game when battery is above 20%. So, I wonder if low battery percentage can affect heating.  Or maybe there are other reasons. I use Lineage OS 15.1.

Comment: Yes it can. At lower battery level the charging rate is high. As level rises charging amperes decrease. Additionally this can be due to background processes. What you do with KillApps, rebooting and Dr. Booster looks pointless to me. There are better and certain ways to keep CPU usage at minimum. Cellular/WiFi signal strength and screen brightness are also major factors in heating.

Comment: Not sure if I'm right but maybe cleaning ram also helps.

Comment: Reboot doesn't clean RAM?

Comment: Yes, I read that it cleans but I remember that phone was burning my fingers after reboot, Killapps and Dr. Booster, full signal of cellular data. Now I tried on strong Wifi, cleaned ram, Killapps and it wasn't heat so much. These tries don't look very different for me.

Comment: Actually it heated up, not immediately but in 1h about.

Comment: Cleaning apps that wipe the RAM are pointless, period. The RAM is _made_ to be filled, because your device will do nothing if it's empty. Killing apps is _mostly_ pointless, as many of those are restarted by Android, thus wasting even more processing power. If your game is resource hungry, the game itself is the most likely cause of overheating.

Comment: @Grimoire I noticed that some apps restart. Is there any way to disable restarting? I tried an app called Task Manager by NEON TEAM but it doesn't work.

Comment: @vasik988 Back then, one would've needed root privileges or certain ROMs. I'm not certain about current Android versions.

Comment: @Grimoire The app I mentioned requires root privilegies but still doesn't work.